# How to define IP Address in DockerFile for H2 Database

Tags: docker, h2, dockerfile

When i run my docker file to run the H2 database it allocate the IP address automatically.

How to set the IP address by environment so docker only allows two ip address for TCP connection and HTTP connection.

```
FROM klousiaj/oracle-java:7.79
MAINTAINER J.P. Klousia <klousiaj>

ENV DOWNLOAD http://www.h2database.com/h2-2016-10-31.zip
ENV DATA_DIR /opt/h2-data

RUN curl ${DOWNLOAD} -o h2.zip \
    && unzip h2.zip -d /opt/ \
    && rm h2.zip \
    && mkdir -p ${DATA_DIR}

EXPOSE 8082 9092

CMD java -cp /opt/h2/bin/h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server \
    -web -webAllowOthers -webPort 8082 \
    -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -tcpPort 9092 \
    -baseDir ${DATA_DIR}

VOLUME ${DATA_DIR}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use any static ips in the docker paradigm, as far as you can.

If you wont a service to talk to a different one, you use the service name you defined in the docker-compose file, lets say "db"

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: klousiaj/oracle-java:7.79
  app:
    image: busybox
```

So from app, you can connect to the db using `telnet db $dbport`, e.g. in terms of mysql, you go with `telnet db 3306`.

Of course, db can allso connect to anyu ports on app using `telnet app`.

You never want to handle IPs or networks yourself, only if you really really have to ( very rare cases ).

If you want to access the app-web port from the host, you will expose that one to the host

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: klousiaj/oracle-java:7.79
  app:
    image: nginx
    port:
      - 80:80
```

This means, you can now use your host ip to access the port 80 of nginx of app, "wget http://:80